# Set Variable Array length?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, dynamic

I am using C++ Builder for programming iOS Applications . In my application I set an array of TImage

```
  TImage *Image[10] ;
```

But i dont know the length of the array at runtime. So how do i replace the 10 for a variable to set a variable array length. When i just replace the 10 for an integer Variable i get an erfror that the Array cant be declared with a Variable length

Comment: You use a `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector<TImage*> Image(10);
```

Or you could use a dynamically allocated array (but I would **strongly** suggest using a `std::vector` instead)

```
TImage** Image = new TImage*[10];
// later
delete[] Image;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I did it with an dynamic allocated array cause i don't  have any experience with vectors. I tried to declare it with vector but i get an error : vector is not implemented in std::

Comment: @Philip1895 Did you `#include <vector>` in your file?

Comment: @Philip1895 do you have experience with dynamic memory allocation? Because that's much harder than using vector.

Comment: Could you explain me the difference between vector and arrays ? why should i use vector ? No i don't have much experience with dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @Philip1895 The short story is that the number of elements of `std::array` must be known at compile time, and then it is fixed size. `std::vector` can be known at run-time, and the size can change, but it is allocated from the heap. Both can be treated as arrays (since they both are under the hood) so they are contiguous, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you very helpful answer. It solved my problem now :)

Comment: I got a new problem . How to refresh the length of array ? Because when c counts more then at from create i have to refresh the length of the array (c)

Comment: @Philip1895 If you don't initially size the vector, then instead of saying `Image[5] = something`, you can say `Image.push_back(something)`. It will then increase the array if needed to store that item.

Comment: Ok but when i defined it like : vector<TImage*> Image(c); how would the push_back call would be ? Image.push_back(c) ?